# redirect based authentication flow in secured by keycloak node.js app behind application gateway

Tags: node.js, docker, keycloak, api-gateway, keycloak-services

I'm getting access denied errors in secured node.js app which is an [official keycloak example app](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/tree/master/example)

Secured app was dockerized and put behind application gateway which is itself dockerized.

The application gateway is node.js express application which uses http/https packages and routes incoming traffic to node.js secured app.

So, to access app url mapped urls were added to the gateway:

```
 mappings:
    - /:/
    - /login:/login        
    - /logout:/logout
    - /protected/resource:/protected/resource
```

Gateway does ssl offloading. 
Keycloak was dockerized too and its */auth* endpoint was mapped inside the gateway.

The app code is below:

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-nodejs-connect');
var hogan = require('hogan-express');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3005, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', require('path').join(__dirname, '/view'));
app.engine('html', hogan);

app.enable('trust proxy')
var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

// Additional configuration is read from keycloak.json file
// installed from the Keycloak web console.

var keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
});

app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout',
  admin: '/',
  protected: '/protected/resource'
}));

app.get('/login', keycloak.protect(), function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    result: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(req.session['keycloak-token']), null, 4),
    event: '1. Authentication\n2. Login'
  });
});

app.get('/protected/resource', keycloak.enforcer(['resource:view', 'resource:write'], {
  resource_server_id: 'nodejs-apiserver'
}), function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    result: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(req.session['keycloak-token']), null, 4),
    event: '1. Access granted to Default Resource\n'
  });
});
```

*keycloak.json* is:

```
{
  "realm" : "nodejs-example",
  "realm-public-key" : "[public_key]",
  "auth-server-url" : "https://[https://[gateway_url]]/auth",
  "ssl-required" : "none",
  "resource" : "nodejs-connect",
  "public-client" : true
}
```

When *https://[gateway_url]/* is accessed in the browser, KeyCloak redirects to login ui, user/password is entered in the login ui and after that access denied error is seen in the browser.

Below error is popped in the app logs:

> Could not obtain grant code error:   { Error: self signed certificate
>   in certificate chain

So basically the app fails to exchange authorization code for access token.

**What i tried:**

1) Accessing Keycloak token endpoint with curl as follows succeeds (Access/Refresh token is returned):

```
 curl -k --key [keypath] --cert [certpath:passphrase] -d "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=nodejs-connect&redirect_uri=https://[gw_url]/login?auth_callback=1&client_session_state=[client_state]&code=[authz_code]
     -X POST 'https://[gw_url]/auth/realms/nodejs-example/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

2) changing "*auth-server-url*" to "***https***://[gateway_url]:**8080**/auth" in *keycloak.json* helped too. Access token is returned. 8080 is published port of Keycloak docker container.

So, i guess the issue is that node.js adapter in the app doesn't present ssl ceritificate to gateway when it wants to replace the authz code with access token. So i tried to change auth-server-url to relative /auth. However

> Could not obtain grant code error:   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:80

is popped inside the logs of the app.

How to configure keycloak node.js adapter correctly to secure services behind the application gateway?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I just had the same error and fixed by putting in the LAN ip Address in the keycloak.json instead of the host name.

Comment: I'm using traefik, and this worked for me. Instead of using keycloak.localhost I used the ip http://172.22.0.6:8080/auth and it worked like a charm.